# Trying to calculate overtime hours

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need help calculating overtime even to double time hours.
As you can see in the image I need it to total regular time to 8 hours then any hours more than 8 to calculate into the next box and so forth for double time. I need it to also subtract the lunch break. For some reason my function is giving me 0 and I can not understand why.

[image: Timesheet]

Comment: There could be multiple reason for that, try to evaluate your formula in order to get more info. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-59a201ae-d1dc-4b15-8586-a70aa409b8a7

Comment: I would first determine the best way to calculate the number of hours or minutes between 2 times in excel. There are many posts out there on it. I would test it with various in/out times, not always equal to even hours. From there, you should be able to write your formula for calculating OT and DT.

Answer (score 1):

The 0.5 in E12 is not half an hour but half a day.  `0.5` Formatted as time is `12:00`

You need to convert that to hours:

```
=(F12-D12+(D12>F12)-E12/24)
```

[image]

Then to get the reg time we use MIN():

```
=MIN(F12-D12+(D12>F12)-E12/24,TIME(8,0,0))
```

[image]

Then for the overtime:

```
=F12-D12+(D12>F12)-E12/24-MIN(F12-D12+(D12>F12)-E12/24,TIME(8,0,0))
```

[image]